# Error: Functions are not valid as a React child. Unsure of where error is

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom

This is one of the two errors that I have encountered on the same application from my previous question. Here is the first error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
Routes@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40930:7
div
div
Header@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:581:1
Router@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40867:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40344:7
div
App
```

I am not sure how to debug this entirely so not really sure where it is saying the error exists... Here is the repository: https://github.com/kstaver/React-Portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With react-router v6, you must pass an element as the value of `element` attribue on `Route` component, but you are sendeing component as element. To solve the problem you need to change  `<Route path="/about" element={About} />` to  `<Route path="/about" element={<About />} />` in all your routes. Actually your routes must be configured like this:

```
 <Routes>
   <Route exact path="/" element={<Navigate to="/about" replace/>} />
   <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
   <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
   <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
   <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />} />
 </Routes>
```